# How to make NaN values in matrix transparent in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, heatmap

I have two figues, a black and white image and a heatmap, with the heatmap overlayed on top of the bw image. My heatmap is outputted into a 2d matrix and I have set values that <= 0 to NaN, expecting when i plot there will be nothing but the background (first image).

Reference images and code:

```
%% Resizing image as well as blending to a particular 'transparency' value (i.e., 'alpha'). 
rgb_at_scale  = imresize(rgb_at,[30 460],'nearest');
rgb_at_scale_2 = rgb_at_scale;
toto          = zeros(size(rgb_at_scale_2));
alpha = 0.6;
rgb_blend = alpha * (rgb_at_scale) + (1 - alpha) * toto.*(0.5);
rgb_blend_final = rgb_blend;
rgb_blend_final(rgb_blend_final <= 0) = nan;


%% Blending heatmap with orginal_image %%
img = 47;
figure('Color', 'k');
ax1 = axes;
imagesc(X_1, Z_1, 10*log10(R1_contrast(:,:,img)),[115 145]);
colormap(ax1,'gray');
ax = gca;
h=xlabel('Lateral(mm)'); %or h=get(gca,'xlabel')
set(h, 'FontSize', 20); 
set(h,'FontWeight','bold');%bold font
z=ylabel('Depth(mm)');
set(z, 'FontSize', 20);
set(z, 'FontWeight', 'bold');
box(ax,'off'); 
set(gca, 'XColor', 'white', 'FontSize', 14); % set x-axis color to white
set(gca, 'YColor', 'white', 'FontSize', 14);
set(gca, 'FontWeight', 'bold');
hold on;
% blended_img_additions %
im = imagesc(rgb_blend_final, 'XData', [-5 5], 'YData', [3.35 6.65]); % adjusting coordinates of HM over original image
ax2 = axes;
im.AlphaData = max(rgb_blend_final,[],3);% Setting the alpha blend to it's highest transparency value '3'
colormap(ax2, 'jet');caxis([0 2.5]);
ax2.Visible = 'off';
linkprop([ax1 ax2],'Position');
% Create colorbar
c = colorbar('peer',ax2,'FontWeight', 'bold','FontSize',20,...
    'Color',[0.941176470588235 0.941176470588235 0.941176470588235]);
c.Label.String = 'Time (sec)';
%savefig(['at_heatmap_test_2' '.fig']);
hold off
```

[image]

How do I make the red be transparent in the image? I've tried adjusting the AlphaData command but still showing red.

Comment: The red is no <=0 therefore not nan, therefore not transparent, right? according to your explanation at least

Comment: It my matrix it shows all values that are <= 0 as NaN. Should I change that line to something else? I also used set(im, 'AlphaData', ~isnan(rgb_blend_final)); and that did not work

Comment: I am confused of what you want. The test seem to suggest that 1) you want nothing of the heatmap plotted 2) that you want the red not plotted. It is not clear what you want, so it is hard to help you

Comment: Basically the NaN values in my matrix are still showing up in my heatmap - instead of showing just the background (transparency). Idk why that is and am trying to fix that.

Comment: You can either set it as [here](https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2009/02/18/image-overlay-using-transparency/) or concatenate the alpha channel to your RBG image as [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/57664-how-to-add-alpha-channel-to-the-image-and-convert-that-image-into-png-format). Next time, please strip your code to only the essential. That makes it easier to follow